# Implementing memoize pattern in JavaScript for multiple values

Tags: javascript, memoization

I'm trying to play a bit and implementing a memoization pattern for multiple values using JavaScript.
I managed to write the code for single value:

```js
var lazy = {};
lazy.memoization = evaluator => {
  const cache = new Map;

  return key => {
    cache.has(key) || cache.set(key, evaluator(key));

    return cache.get(key);
  };
};

var memoize = lazy.memoization(key => console.log('computing ', key));
memoize(1); // -> computing 1
memoize(2); // -> computing 2
```

Here is the version for multiple keys and it does not work as expected, it just outputs 'computing Array []', 'computing undefined':

```js
var lazy = {};
lazy.memoization = evaluator => {
  const cash = new Map;

  return (...keys) => {
    var values = [];
    keys.reduce((v, f) => {
      if (!cash.has(v)) {
        cash.set(v, evaluator(v));
      }

      values.push(cash.get(v));
    }, values);

    return values;
  };
};

var memoizeMultiple = lazy.memoization((...keys) => {
  keys.forEach(key => console.log('computing ', key))
});
memoizeMultiple(1, 2);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You are running `evaluator` for each argument passed in. Is that the intention or are you supposed to cache the result of calling `evaluator` with all of the arguments?

Comment: More to the point, you mention "it does not work as expected", but don't tell us what you expect :).

Comment: There are several problems with the `reduce` call: You're using `v` as though it were the key, but the key is `f`; you're not returning anything from the callback, so on subsequent trips `v` is `undefined`; you're not using the return value (which almost always means you shouldn't be using `reduce`).

Comment: On a separate note, `cache` is the correct term for something that is held in memory (in this case). "cash" means money.

Comment: @VLAZ Ye, you're right, thanks for the remark about 'cash'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code. First off, `reduce` is a kind of `fold`, which means it usually is used to "collapse" a data structure into a single value. In order to do this, the function passed into `reduce` gets the *accumulation* value first and each value inside the data structure second.

```
const sumOf = ns => ns.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0);

sumOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // -> 15
```

In this example, the data structure is an `Array`, which holds `Number` values. `reduce` is used to collapse *all numbers in the array into a final value* (by summing them up). The collapsing function is called a *reducer function* (it does addition in this example). Finally, the `0` passed into reduce is the *seed* value.

Let's track down what happens step by step:

In the first iteration, the reducer function is passed the seed value and the first number in the array. It therefor looks like:

```
(0, 1) => 0 + 1
```

The second iteration starts with the result from the first iteration as the accumulator value and the second number in the array:

```
(1, 2) => 1 + 2
```

So in complete, it works like this:

```
(0, 1) => 0 + 1
(1, 2) => 1 + 2
(3, 3) => 3 + 3
(6, 4) => 6 + 4
(10, 5) => 10 + 5
```

After the last iteration, `reduce` returns the final accumulator, which is `15` in this example.

OK, back to the code you provided. Your "multi arguments memoization" version uses `reduce`, but the reducer function doesn't return the intermediate results as a new accumulator value and you don't return the final result `reduce` produces.

Another problem is your `evaluator` function. The value it returns is stored inside the caching `Map` instance. In your code, it *doesn't return anything other than `undefined`*. Therefor, `undefined` is stored and returned on subsequent calls to the memoized function.

If we address these issues, it works:

```js
var lazy = {};
lazy.memoization = evaluator => {
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((acc, arg) => {
      if (!cache.has(arg)) {
        cache.set(arg, evaluator(arg)); // stores the returned value inside the cache variable
      }

      return acc.concat(cache.get(arg));
    }, []); // the result should be an array, so use that as the seed
  };
};

var memoizeMultiple = lazy.memoization(value => {
  console.log('computing ', value)
  return value; // you have to return something in here, because the return value is stored
});

memoizeMultiple(1, 2);
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit. Happy coding!

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.